# if statement in SQL and

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am selecting files but when the name begins with a certain sequence i want it to also have a certain field like this

```
select filename from filestable where
filename like '%abc_%' and not filename like '%abc2%'
```

// here i didnt wanna use escape character and just skip abc2 filename and then create a second query for it(kinda retarded) coz I repeat the query and union the result

```
    select filename from filestable 
    inner join filetype on filetype.id = filename.id 
    where
    filename like '%abc2%'
    and filetype.type = 'mpeg'
```

I want to make them both into one query with and if perhaps ?

Comment: But I don't understand - why don't you do UNION right there in the first query?

Comment: I am new, am not sure I expected there is something direct like if its this then filetype.type ='mpeg'

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve on a high level, could you try explain it a bit clearer? Like with some example input and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are combining the two using a `join`, then I think this is the equivalent query:

```
select distinct ft.filename
from filestable ft left join
     filetype fty
     on fty.id = ft.id 
where (ft.filename like '%abc_%' and not ft.filename like '%abc2%') or
      (ft.filename like '%abc2%' and fty.type = 'mpeg');
```

If you know that there are no duplicates in `filetype` for a given `filename`, then just use `select` instead of `select distinct`.

Comment: I guess this is also the fastest compared to the other solutions ? they seem longer in text at least :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT filename FROM filestable 
WHERE filename LIKE '%abc_%'
      AND ( filename NOT LIKE '%abc2%'
            OR EXISTS (
                 SELECT 1 FROM filetype
                 WHERE filetype.id = filename.id 
                       AND filetype.type = 'mpeg'
      ));
```